# Javascript canvas animating

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to make a loading bar for my web application and I want to use a html canvas for this. This is the script that I use to fill up the canvas:

```
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("bar");
    var c = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var xPos = 0;

    draw = function() {
        if(xPos < 300){
            c.rect(0, 0, xPos, 30);
            c.fill(255,0,0);
            xPos += 0.5;
        }
    };
</script>
```

I tested this code on a online code converter (khan academy) and it worked (of course without the first 2 lines and c. in front of most things), and that is also my trouble I don't know where I have to put c. in front of?

I simplified the page a little bit:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="bar"></canvas>
        <script>
            var canvas = document.getElementById("bar");
            var c = canvas.getContext("2d");

            c.fillStyle = "#ff0000"

            draw = function(){
                if(xPos < 300){
                    c.fillRect(0, 0, xPos, 30);
                    xPos += 0.5;
                }
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to call that function? E.g. execute `draw()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you are trying to draw... this:

```
draw = function(){
    if(xPos < 300) {
        c.fillRect(0, 0, xPos, 30);
        xPos += 0.5;
    }
};
```

... it is a **definition** of variable in global context (context of `window` object), then assigning a function to it. That's all - it only **defines** the behavior.

What you need also needs to **execute** that (a *sidenote*: to execute it after the canvas is actually created - when you put code in a `script` tag after canvas tag - it's sufficient and you did it already).

To execute the function use:

```
draw();
```

Or don't wrap code in function at all (unless it's to be called multiple times).

Or use a syntax construct to execute the function created in place like this:

```
(draw = function(){
    if(xPos < 300) {
        c.fillRect(0, 0, xPos, 30);
        xPos += 0.5;
        setTimeout(draw,15); // use this to achieve animation effect
    }
})();
```

```js
var xPos = 0;
var canvas = document.getElementById("bar");
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
c.fillStyle = "#FF0000";

var draw;
(draw = function(){
    if(xPos < 300) {
        c.fillRect(0, 0, xPos, 30);
        xPos += 0.5;
        setTimeout(draw,15);
    }
})();
```

```css
#bar {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="bar"></canvas>
```

**Edit**: I've been thinking of what you might need, as it's not entirely abvious what you want. I have created [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xqL6tw6e/). Maybe it'll be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...

You got some things mixed up. Try this:

```
<html>
<canvas id = "cvs1" width = "300" height = "30"></canvas>
</html>
```

And for the script:

```
var c = document.getElementById("cvs1").getContext("2d");
c.fillStyle = "#ff0000" //Set Fill Color(Set to red)

    if(xPos < 300){
        c.fillRect(xPos, 0, 30, 30);
        xPos += 0.5;
    }
```

If not:

What you did was use fill and rect seperately. You need to set the color, and then use the fillRect() function to draw the rectangle.

EDIT: You got the x,y,width,height as width,height,x,y. Fixed answer.

Good luck!

Comment: It didn't work me but it might be because i'm running this website on wampserver?

Comment: Mabye... try this: http://apache.mirror.rafal.ca//httpd/binaries/win32/httpd-2.2.25-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8y.msi

Comment: Oh no I do have a Apache server, it is build in on wampserver otherwise I couldn´t be running all the other php codes

Comment: If your like me, than you like hosting things on your own, but maybe getting some web hosting would be the better choice? I mean, it is all up to you, but, it does seem to be working better on other services.

Comment: Eventually I will host it online but the site is far from done so

Comment: try looking at the pure code, on your local computer without the php.

Comment: I rebuild the page in a small test but still no moving bar.

Comment: I fixed the answer try that.

Comment: I didn´t make that wrong it is supposed to extend over time not move away from its actual position, the starting point must stay the same while the width grows longer until it reaches 300px.

Comment: Here this is what it is supposed to do:

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/spin-off-of-test/4667014854737920

Comment: hmmm... Have you tried using the html element to do this?

Comment: wait- are you using the javascript canvas for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `draw` for every animation step. You could do this using `setTimeout`, `setInterval` or `requestAnimationFrame` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="bar"></canvas>
        <script>
            var canvas = document.getElementById("bar");
            var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
            c.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
            xPos=0;
            draw = function(){
                if(xPos < 300){
                    c.fillRect(0, 0, xPos, 30);
                    xPos += 0.5;
                    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
                }
            };
            requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```